# How to do-while loop to minus my cash 15.35 with array input in VB .NET Console

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code and how I can do the loop to get each array minus the cash?
I able to do until reserve the input and split it into one digit. I want that one digit minus my cash 1 by 1.

'Name containing class MessageBox
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    'Declare variable
    Dim studentID, sID As Integer
    Dim cash As Integer = 15.35

    'Prompt user to enter student ID with 9 digit
    Console.Write("Please Enter Student ID (9 Digit): ")

    'Check for valid student ID is integer else will give error
    If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), studentID) Then
        Console.WriteLine()

        'Read & Write out student ID from input
        Console.Write("You Entered Student ID: " & studentID)
        Console.WriteLine()

        'reverse character order of a specified string
        Dim studentID2 As String = StrReverse(studentID)

        'Write out the ID number
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID reversed: " & studentID2)
        Console.WriteLine()

        'Split student ID into individual number use For-next
        For Each getstdID As Char In studentID2
            'Write out the ID number to a single ID

            sID = Integer.Parse(getstdID)
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
            Console.WriteLine()

            Do While sID <> 0
                cash = sID - cash
                Console.WriteLine("RM-" & sID, "-RM" & cash)
                sID /= 10
            Loop

        Next

    Else
        'error if input not number
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid integer")
    End If

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: `Integer` does not store decimal points or floating point numbers.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
This is my Assignment question as below and may I get help?::
Suppose that you only have RM15.35 in cash. There are varieties of fruit to buy with all your money. The prices of fruit are those individual numbers of your student ID, respectively.
Create the required VB objects to loop those prices (numbers from right to left order of your Student ID) with the following repetition statements. Determine the remaining balance cash in your pocket using the Windows Console App (a VB .Net project).
i) do-while loop
ii) do-until loop
iii) do-loop while loop
iv) do-loop until loop

Comment: First now and forever turn on Option Strict in Project Properties and set it in Options for all future projects.

Comment: "I want that one digit minus my cash" I think you want the one digit to be subtracted from the starting cash of 15.35 but you write `cash = sID - cash` which subtracts the cash from the one digit.

Comment: `sID /= 10` What is the purpose of this line?

Comment: @Mary yes..i want to subtract from the starting cash of 15.35. --> sID /= 10 this to stop the while i guess

Comment: @Marry I am totally new to VB.NET and can guide me on how to point it in a correct way or any example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn on Option Strict you will see errors between String, Char, Integer, and Decimal. You need to aware of the conversions that are necessary.

I hate to disagree with your teacher but the only place I can see to use a Do loop is for the `Integer` validation.

The actual spending of the money lends itself to a `For Each` loop iterating through each of the digits in the reversed Id. I hope you can convince your teacher to accept this.

I put in a few examples of an interpolated string indicated by the `$` preceding the string. You can then insert variables directly in the string surrounded by `{ }`. It is easier to write without all the ampersands and double quotes.

```
Sub Main()
    'Prompt user to enter student ID with 9 digit
    Console.Write("Please Enter Student ID (9 Digit): ")
    Dim IdString = Console.ReadLine
    'Check for valid student ID is integer else will give error
    Dim studentID As Integer
    Do Until Integer.TryParse(IDString, studentID)
        'error if input not number
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid integer, try again.")
        IdString = Console.ReadLine
    Loop
    'Use the .net Array.Reverse method rather than the vb specific StrReverse
    Dim IDChar = IdString.ToCharArray
    Array.Reverse(IDChar)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Read & Write out student ID from input
    Console.Write("You Entered Student ID: " & studentID)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Write out the ID number
    Dim ReverseIDString As String = New String(IDChar)
    Console.WriteLine("Student ID reversed: " & ReverseIDString)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Split student ID into individual number use For-next
    Dim cash As Decimal = 15.35D
    For Each Digit As Char In IDChar
        Dim sID = CInt(Digit.ToString)
        If cash < sID Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Your next purchase is for RM{sID}. You don't have enough cash RM{cash}")
            Exit For
        End If
        'Write out the ID number to a single digit
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
        Console.WriteLine()
        cash -= sID
        Console.WriteLine($"RM-{sID}, -RM{cash}")
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

To use a `Do` loop you need to keep track of the index in the array which isn't necessary in a `For Each`.

```
Sub Main()
    'Prompt user to enter student ID with 9 digit
    Console.Write("Please Enter Student ID (9 Digit): ")
    Dim IdString = Console.ReadLine
    'Check for valid student ID is integer else will give error
    Dim studentID As Integer
    Do Until Integer.TryParse(IDString, studentID)
        'error if input not number
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid integer, try again.")
        IdString = Console.ReadLine
    Loop
    'Use the .net Array.Reverse method rather than the vb specific StrReverse
    Dim IDChar = IdString.ToCharArray
    Array.Reverse(IDChar)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Read & Write out student ID from input
    Console.Write("You Entered Student ID: " & studentID)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Write out the ID number
    Dim ReverseIDString As String = New String(IDChar)
    Console.WriteLine("Student ID reversed: " & ReverseIDString)
    Console.WriteLine()
    'Call any of the SpendMoney (1,2,3,4) subs here for the same result.
    SpendMoney4(IDChar)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Notice that the conditions of the `Do` is a bit different depending if the condition is at the top of the loop or the bottom and whether it is While or Until.

```
Private Sub SpendMoney1(CashArray As Char())
    Dim cash As Decimal = 15.35D
    Dim CashArrayIndex As Integer
    Do While CashArrayIndex < CashArray.Length
        Dim sID = CInt(CashArray(CashArrayIndex).ToString)
        If cash < sID Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Your next purchase is for RM{sID}. You don't have enough cash RM{cash}")
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Write out the ID number to a single digit
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
        Console.WriteLine()
        cash -= sID
        Console.WriteLine($"RM-{sID}, -RM{cash}")
        CashArrayIndex += 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub SpendMoney2(CashArray As Char())
    Dim cash As Decimal = 15.35D
    Dim CashArrayIndex As Integer
    Do Until CashArrayIndex = CashArray.Length
        Dim sID = CInt(CashArray(CashArrayIndex).ToString)
        If cash < sID Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Your next purchase is for RM{sID}. You don't have enough cash RM{cash}")
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Write out the ID number to a single digit
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
        Console.WriteLine()
        cash -= sID
        Console.WriteLine($"RM-{sID}, -RM{cash}")
        CashArrayIndex += 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub SpendMoney3(CashArray As Char())
    Dim cash As Decimal = 15.35D
    Dim CashArrayIndex As Integer
    Do
        Dim sID = CInt(CashArray(CashArrayIndex).ToString)
        If cash < sID Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Your next purchase is for RM{sID}. You don't have enough cash RM{cash}")
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Write out the ID number to a single digit
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
        Console.WriteLine()
        cash -= sID
        Console.WriteLine($"RM-{sID}, -RM{cash}")
        CashArrayIndex += 1
    Loop While CashArrayIndex < CashArray.Length
End Sub

Private Sub SpendMoney4(CashArray As Char())
    Dim cash As Decimal = 15.35D
    Dim CashArrayIndex As Integer
    Do
        Dim sID = CInt(CashArray(CashArrayIndex).ToString)
        If cash < sID Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Your next purchase is for RM{sID}. You don't have enough cash RM{cash}")
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Write out the ID number to a single digit
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID into individual number: " & sID)
        Console.WriteLine()
        cash -= sID
        Console.WriteLine($"RM-{sID}, -RM{cash}")
        CashArrayIndex += 1
    Loop Until CashArrayIndex = CashArray.Length
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a huge help and Thank you so much for the guidance! I Will try this out and will talk with my teacher according to your suggestion. Thanks Alot! Appreciate it.

Comment: It works as I want and I have commented out the IF if not enough cash since the program still needs minus the cash until getting the negative amount. thank you so much.